# dose pip3 is backwards compatibility as pip2

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

until now we install all python modules with `pip2` on some server Linux RHEL machine

due some problems we notice that `pip2` not works properly and we get the following errors ( when we run `pip2 list` or `pip2 installed`

example (down) , from pip2 list ( but the same when we are installing python module )

therefore we installed `pip3` , and `pip3` is fine and we can get `pip3 list` and also we can installe with `pip3`

so my question is that : can we use `pip3` to installed all modules for python2 and python3 ?

dose `pip3` backwards compatibility with `pip2`  ?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==20.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.package_finder import PackageFinder
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/index/package_finder.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.index.collector import parse_links
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_internal/index/collector.py", line 14, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import html5lib, requests
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py", line 97, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-20.1.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 48, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl import backend as openssl_backend
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.backend import backend
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/backend.py", line 37, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.backends.openssl.x509 import _Certificate
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/x509.py", line 24, in <module>
    class _Certificate(object):
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/utils.py", line 23, in register_decorator
    verify_interface(iface, klass)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/utils.py", line 43, in verify_interface
    actual = inspect.getargspec(getattr(klass, method))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/inspect.py", line 815, in getargspec
    raise TypeError('{!r} is not a Python function'.format(func))
TypeError: <method-wrapper '__ne__' of type object at 0x35dad00> is not a Python function
```

example with `pip3` that works

```
pip3 list
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        19.3.1
setuptools 41.6.0
```

Comment: Is there a compelling reason to continue to use Python 2.x?

Comment: python2 is installed but also python3 , but my question is diif , because I cant used pip2 so I want to ask if we can use pip3 instead and dose pip3 support everything as pip2